# First time with webpage: How can I hide the header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's my first time building a web site and I don't know how to force hiding the header when scrolling down. I downloaded a cool free template of web site which is very cool but complex. I know the basics of web design: I have the HTML file when I have the header calling the class main-header from the CSS styles and then, the javascript scripts are called at the end of the HTML script.

```
  <!-- Start Main Top -->
<header class="main-header">
    <!-- Start Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-default bootsnav">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Start Header Navigation -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu" aria-controls="navbars-rs-food" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <!-- End Header Navigation -->

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" data-in="fadeInDown" data-out="fadeOutUp">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html"> About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

            <!-- Start Atribute Navigation -->
            <div class="attr-nav">
                <ul>
                    <li class="search"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- End Atribute Navigation -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End Navigation -->
</header>
```

I'm using that code on the HTML file and then, I have created the following JS script to hide the header:

```
    /* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("header").style.top = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
```

and the style.css portion of the code related to that header is:

```
    .main-header.fixed-menu {
     position: fixed;
     visibility: hidden;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0px 0px;
     background: #ffffff;
     z-index: 0;
     transition: all 500ms ease;
     -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
     -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
     -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
     -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
     z-index: 999;
     opacity: 1;
     visibility: visible;
     -ms-animation-name: fadeInDown;
     -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
     -op-animation-name: fadeInDown;
     -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
     animation-name: fadeInDown;
     -ms-animation-duration: 500ms;
     -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
     -op-animation-duration: 500ms;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
     animation-duration: 500ms;
     -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
     -op-animation-timing-function: linear;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
     animation-timing-function: linear;
     -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
     -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
     -op-animation-iteration-count: 1;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
     animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
 .main-header.fixed-menu {
     padding: 0px;
     box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
     border-radius: 0;
}
```

I really don't get where is the problem or if there is anything wrong with the code. I am not proficient with HTML and web design so I need your help! :)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to remove `position: fixed;
     visibility: hidden;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;` from     .main-header.fixed-menu {

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/max_max/evoa80jc/

Answer (score 0):

As [s.kuznetsov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13573444/s-kuznetsov) proposed you are missing some things:

1. In `<header class="main-header">` you are missing `id="header"` and the second class `fixed-menu` so the correct result would be `<header id="header" class="main-header fixed-menu">`
2. As the page content is not longer than the window you are using for testing the scroll event cannot happen so you need to add content to your html like `<body></body>` and assign height in the css `body { height: 200vh; background-color: black;}`
3. Other than that I would modify the js 
   from `document.getElementById("header").style.top = "-50px";` 
   to `document.getElementById("header").style.top = "-100%";`

```js
 /* When the user scrolls down, hide the navbar. When the user scrolls up, show the navbar */
 var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
 window.onscroll = function() {
   var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
   if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
     document.getElementById("header").style.top = "0";
   } else {
     document.getElementById("header").style.top = "-100%";
   }
   prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
 }
```

```css
 .main-header.fixed-menu {
   position: fixed;
   visibility: hidden;
   left: 0px;
   top: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 0px 0px;
   background: #ffffff;
   z-index: 0;
   transition: all 500ms ease;
   -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
   -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
   -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
   z-index: 999;
   opacity: 1;
   visibility: visible;
   -ms-animation-name: fadeInDown;
   -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
   -op-animation-name: fadeInDown;
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
   animation-name: fadeInDown;
   -ms-animation-duration: 500ms;
   -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
   -op-animation-duration: 500ms;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
   animation-duration: 500ms;
   -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
   -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
   -op-animation-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -op-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
 }

 .main-header.fixed-menu {
   padding: 0px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
   border-radius: 0;
 }
 
 body {
   height: 200vh;
   background-color: black;
 }
```

```html
<!-- Start Main Top -->
<header id="header" class="main-header fixed-menu">
  <!-- Start Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-default bootsnav">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Start Header Navigation -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu" aria-controls="navbars-rs-food" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <!-- End Header Navigation -->

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" data-in="fadeInDown" data-out="fadeOutUp">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.html"> About Us</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

      <!-- Start Atribute Navigation -->
      <div class="attr-nav">
        <ul>
          <li class="search"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- End Atribute Navigation -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navigation -->
</header>
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: That's great bro. Thank you and s.kuznetsov for the help. I have tried out your code but it does not work on my web page! I mean, technically it is great, and I have learnt it but on my web page it looks like it tries to remove the header but it comes back instantly after some microseconds. I guess that this is the price to pay for using someone's webpage template. I have removed the fixed property on the style.css and now I remove the whole header when going down, but not that cool as you suggested...